# Map between localizations induces map on underlying modules for Zariski covering

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

While working through a proof of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.04148.pdf) paper,<sup>1</sup> at the middle of page 45, the author's claim of a short exact sequence seems to amount to the following problem:

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $s,t\in A$ which generate the unit ideal. Suppose also that $M,N$ are modules over $A$.
>
> Suppose that we have maps between the localizations
>   $$
> f_s:M_s\rightarrow N_s
> $$
>   $$f_t:M_t\rightarrow N_t$$
>   $$f_{st}:M_{st}\rightarrow N_{st}
> $$
>   such that the diagram
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   $$\begin{CD}
>  M_s @>f_s  > > N_s\\
>  @V  V V @V  V V\\
>  M_{st} @>  >f_{st} > N_{st}
> \end{CD}$$
>   and the analogous one for $t$ commute.
>
> Does there exist a map $f:M\rightarrow N$ making all the relevant diagrams commute?

I thought that applying the theory of the faithfully flat descent for $A\rightarrow A_{s}\times A_{t}$ could be a good idea here but led me nowhere.

<sup>1</sup>Bhargav Bhatt, Jacob Lurie: *A Riemann-Hilbert correspondence in positive characteristic*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04148

Comment: Unless there is some subtlety that I missed, this should probably be moved to MathStackExchange.

Comment: The same question on Mathematics: [Map between localizations induces map on underlying modules for Zariski covering](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3226382). I think that [this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638) on MathOverflow Meta gives very reasonable suggestions on [meta-tag:cross-posting].  (On an unrelated note, the tag (abstract-algebra) is deprecated on MO, see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/abstract-algebra/info).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This* follows immediately from the fact that the presheaf $\mathcal{Hom}(\tilde{M},\tilde{N})$ (Hartshorne's notation) on $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ given by

$$U\mapsto Hom(\tilde{M}|_U,\tilde{N}|_U)$$

[is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294802/prove-that-sheaf-hom-is-a-sheaf) a sheaf in the Zariski topology. In particular, it verifies the gluing condition (given your two commuting square diagrams for $s$ and $t$) for its sections on an open cover $\{U_s,U_t\}$ such as the one in the question.

* I'm talking about the assertion in the question, not the linked paper